# Problems with multidimension arrays in C++ again

Tags: c++

I passed a multidimension array to a function in a reverse call like this:

```
template<int size>
void print_multidimension_array(int A[][size], int &cnt){
  if(cnt <= 0){
       return;
  }
  else{
      int (*B)[size];
      print_multidimension_array(B, cnt--);
  }

}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  int A[3][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
  int count = 5;
  print_multidimension_array(A, count);
}
```

I didn't get any compilation error but after I put it into running I was told that "no matching function to call 'print_multidimension_array'".Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: That *is* a compilation error.

Comment: @sftrabbit : so how can I fix it?

Comment: Definitely compilation error: http://ideone.com/0a4kom

Answer (score 9):

`cnt--` returns a *copy* of the old value of `cnt`. That is a temporary *rvalue* which can't be bound to a reference - so it can't be used as the second argument to your function.

I suspect you want `--cnt`. That gives a *lvalue* referring to the new value, which can be bound to a reference.

Taking the argument by value would fix the compiler error; but you'd still need to pre-decrement to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I did followed your suggestion.It works well now.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
void print_multidimension_array(int A[][size], int &cnt){
```

to:

```
void print_multidimension_array(int A[][size], int cnt){
```

Comment: That will force the code to compile, but you'll still have the infinite loop caused by using post-decrement instead of pre-decrement.

Comment: Yes, I had encountered a infinite loop problem before.Thanks for all your help.